# get albumid using album name OR get created album albumid from picasa in picasa-php-zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, picasa

I want to get Album ID of created album

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Photos::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Photos($client);

$entry = new Zend_Gdata_Photos_AlbumEntry();
$entry->setTitle($service->newTitle("firstalbum"));

$values = $service->insertAlbumEntry($entry);
var_dump($values); ////display lots of no. of line of result with AlbumID,URL...
```

$values return a lots of lines of results and it's contains something like 
["Location"]=> string(130) "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/113978572163857330101/albumid/6050448340724330593/1?authkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
I want to get Album ID from this but I don't know how to get it. I tried to get "Location" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the album ID using returned $values object
$value->getGphotoId();

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to get AlbumID from Zend_Gdata_Photos_AlbumEntry, you must use

```
Zend_Gdata_Photos_PhotoEntry::getGphotoAlbumId()
```

You can find examples on Zend and Google sites both:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.photos.html
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php#PhotosInfo

Well, you can retrieve album id after album creation:

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Photos_AlbumQuery();
$query->setAlbumName('firstalbum');
$albumEntry = $service->getAlbumEntry($query);
$albumId = $albumEntry->getGphotoId()->getText();
```

Comment: Actualy I don't know how to get  ["Location"] from returned $values object. Please help me to get "Location" value.

Comment: Change answer to ZF-way, but you found it already minute before )))